# When I have a pointer to a variable, but not a reference, will the garbage collector de-allocate it?

Tags: pointers, garbage-collection, d

In D, when I have a pointer to an object, which has no reference to it, will the garbage collector de-allocate the object?

```
int main() {
    int[]* testvPtr = test();
    // Will testvPtr risk pointing at de-allocated memory? 
    return 0;
}

int[]* test() {
    int[] testv = new int()[5];
    return &testv;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not valid D code. In `test()`, you are returning the address of a local variable, which is invalid as the variable resides on the stack, and the stack frame containing it will cease to exist when that function returns.

To answer the question in the title, the GC will follow all indirections recursively, regardless if they are pointers or references, so as long as you can access a heap object (without using pointer arithmetics or other un-`@safe` stuff), the GC will not free the memory.

Comment: How about if `test()` was an object that'd get destructed afterwards? Would a property or member variable of said object still exist if it had a pointer pointing to it?

Comment: The GC will not collect an object, even if there are only pointers to its fields. By default, all pointers are taken into consideration, regardless of where *inside* the object they are pointing to.

Comment: So I could safely return a pointer to a property which might loose it's reference asynchronously without it suddenly becoming invalid?

Comment: As long as the object that property is from is managed by the GC (i.e. not on the stack, or a RefCounted object), yes.